# Title of 60s/70s TV story of a man who goes to a town hidden by fog

Tags: story-identification, horror

I remember seeing it on TV. It was made in 60s or 70s. It started with a man going to this town that was hidden by fog. The town's people have a secret: they, or something there, eat the dead. I remember them having sharp teeth. The man leaves the town with a woman he met there.

Comment: longline83: When you return, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like the episode "The Ghouls" from the portmanteau horror film "The Monster Club"

[Wikipedia article (beware of spoilers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_Club)

Here's a bit of the plot from the wiki with spoilery info removed:

> A movie director scouting locations for his next film pays a horrifying visit to an isolated, decrepit village, Loughville near Hillington, Norfolk, where the sinister residents refuse to let him leave. He discovers to his horror that the village is inhabited by species of man-eating ghouls who unearth graves for food and clothes. And now there are no more graves to plunder and the ghouls are hungry for flesh. While imprisoned by the ghouls, he meets Luna. Luna advises him to hide in the church, as ghouls cannot cross holy ground. The director with the aid of Luna attempts to escape.

No mention of fog, but I do recall it being shrouded in the stuff.